# Displaying websites in my webview

Tags: java, javascript, android

i have a problem in loading url in my webview. i put my code in onCreate so that when this activity called it would directly load the url in webview widget. I use this code.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_loadurl);

webView_url = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
webView_url.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView_url.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

}
```

Everytime i put this code in my activity it always force close and my logcat error is

```
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to   
start activity  
ComponentInfo{com.example.qrreader/com.example.qrreader.LoadurlActivity}: 
java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    at 
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    at 
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    at 
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    at 
com.example.qrreader.LoadurlActivity.onCreate(LoadurlActivity.java:36)
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    at 
android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    at 
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
08-02 08:37:04.780: E/AndroidRuntime(10321):    ... 11 more
```

Please anyone help me.

Comment: Just checking, do you have permission in place `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` ? Also is `WebView webView_url;` declared outside `onCreate()` ?

Comment: i already add that in my manifest. No, it is inside onCreate, so that when this activity called it will automatically load the url.

Comment: Which line is `LoadurlActivity.java:36` ?

Comment: Are you sure you have a component with id `imageView1` in your layout in `activity_loadurl`? Looks a bit weird that a `WebView` has an id that is more appropriate for an `ImageView`. `findViewById` returns null if there is no view with such id.

Comment: thats the name of my activity. sorry, my post is not clear.

Comment: I understood that. I meant which is line 36 in your activity named `LoadUrlActivity`? Also please post your XML file.

Comment: eeeiiii... yah, OMG. i never notice this one. im so stupid. Thank you very much @EvgenyTanhilevich ...

Comment: @EvgenyTanhilevich: consider posting your comment as an answer. It seems to have solved the issue for the OP. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check if your webview's id is really imageView1 and is really on your R.layout.activity_loadurl .

PS: please don't use confusing ids, like imageView1 on WebView. Use descriptive ones.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check that your LoadurlActivity activity is added in your manifest file?
Something like this for instance,

```
<activity 
 android:name=".LoadurlActivity" 
 android:label="@string/app_name">
</activity>
```

You can check the developer guide about [manifest](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html) for more.